# Does Apex lead conversion trigger Contact before/after insert triggers?

Tags: apex, contact, lead-conversion, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have some updates I'd like to make on converted leads. I had it in my lead code - first convert the lead, then query for the converted contact and update. However, that was triggering CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY.

I refactored it out to update custom fields on lead, mapped them to contact, and put the contact updates in a Contact trigger. 
My tests are failing, indicating that the contact updates aren't happening. When I query the mapped fields, they are updated as expected.

I put some debugging in to both triggers - the before insert on lead, after insert on lead which runs the conversion, and before insert on Contact. I don't see that the contact triggers are firing!

Does anyone know what the order of execution is with Lead conversion/contact triggers?